# index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]' ... Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift3

I am not sure where am I doing wrong.

```
let recievedJson = json
let results = recievedJson["results"] as! NSArray
let resultsDic = results[0] as! NSDictionary
let address = resultsDic["address_components"] as? NSArray
let zipcodeDic = address?[0] as! NSDictionary
let cityNameDic = address?[1] as! NSDictionary
let countyDic = address?[2] as! NSDictionary
let stateDic = address?[3] as! NSDictionary
let countryDic = address?[4] as! NSDictionary
let zipcode = zipcodeDic["long_name"] as! String
let cityName = cityNameDic["long_name"] as! String
let countyName = countyDic["long_name"] as! String
let stateName = stateDic["long_name"] as! String
let stateShortName = stateDic["short_name"] as! String
let countryName = countryDic["long_name"] as! String
let countryShortName = countryDic["short_name"] as! String
```

Trying to retrieve data from this json response

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=23508&sensor=true

This worked for me, small change to @Danh Answer.

```
let recievedJson: [String: Any] = json as! [String : Any]
        if let results = recievedJson["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {

            if results.count > 0 {
                let resultsDic = results[0]

                if let address = resultsDic["address_components"] as? [[String: Any]] {

                    for dict in address {

                        if let longName = dict["long_name"] as? String,
                            let shortName = dict["short_name"] as? String,
                            let types = dict["types"] as? [String] {

                            if types.contains("postal_code") {

                                print("postal_code: \(longName)")
                            } else if types.contains("locality") {

                                print("city: \(longName)")
                            } else if types.contains("administrative_area_level_2") {

                                print("county: \(longName)")
                            } else if types.contains("administrative_area_level_1") {

                                print("state: \(longName)")
                            } else if types.contains("country") {

                                print("country: \(longName)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to make such assumptions. Code defensively. Get rid of all of the `as!` and use `if let ... as? ...`. Check the array count before trying to access a specific index.

Comment: And since you are using Swift, avoid using `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`. Use a Swift dictionary and Swift array with proper type information.

Comment: @rmaddy If I don't use NSArray/NSDictionary, xcode is showing error "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' "

Comment: @Karen Edit your question with new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `address` array has 4 items (has indexes from 0 to 3) but you accessed to item has index is 4, so you got this error. You should use `Optional Binding - if let` to unwrap values and check `count` of an array before subscript. And let use Swift types. The code must be:

```
let recievedJson: [String: Any] = json
    if let results = recievedJson["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {

        if results.count > 0 {
            let resultsDic = results[0]

            if let address = resultsDic["address_components"] as? [[String: Any]] {

                // zipcode
                if address.count > 0 {

                    let zipcodeDic = address[0]
                    if let zipcode = zipcodeDic["long_name"] as? String {
                        print("zipcode: \(zipcode)")
                    }
                }

                // cityName
                if address.count > 1 {

                    let cityNameDic = address[1]
                    if let cityName = cityNameDic["long_name"] as? String {
                        print("cityName: \(cityName)")
                    }
                }

                // stateName
                if address.count > 2 {

                    let stateDic = address[2]
                    if let stateName = stateDic["long_name"] as? String {
                        print("stateName: \(stateName)")
                    }
                    if let stateShortName = stateDic["short_name"] as? String {
                        print("stateShortName: \(stateShortName)")
                    }
                }

                // countryDic
                if address.count > 3 {

                    let countryDic = address[3]
                    if let countryName = countryDic["long_name"] as? String {
                        print("countryName: \(countryName)")
                    }
                    if let countryShortName = countryDic["short_name"] as? String {
                        print("countryShortName: \(countryShortName)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Update: extract address components from Google Maps API

```
let recievedJson: [String: Any] = json
if let results = recievedJson["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {

    if results.count > 0 {
        let resultsDic = results[0]

        if let address = resultsDic["address_components"] as? [[String: Any]] {

            for dict in address {

                if let longName = dict["long_name"] as? String,
                    let shortName = dict["short_name"] as? String,
                    let types = dict["types"] as? [String] {

                    if types.contains("postal_code") {

                        print("postal_code: \(longName)")
                    } else if types.contains("locality") {

                        print("city: \(longName)")
                    } else if types.contains("administrative_area_level_2") {

                        print("county: \(longName)")
                    } else if types.contains("administrative_area_level_1") {

                        print("state: \(longName)")
                    } else if types.contains("country") {

                        print("country: \(longName)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I see some other issue. See below I think county json is missing so country value assigned to stateName.. I think your answer is not completely right..  zipcode: 23508
cityName: Norfolk
countyName: Virginia
stateName: United States
stateShortName: US

Comment: what I meant was in few cases there is county response as 2 element of array, some times not. In code we should also compare with key before assigning the value. See below links for two different responses. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=23508&sensor=true  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=20171&sensor=true

Comment: There is type for the response whether it is country ? administration area.. etc., that should be a comparing parameter.

Comment: Updated: They provided `types`, so you can check this value